# Boundary Curves

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

Planar region D is given by the following conditions
$$25x^2-150x+9y^2\leq 0$$
$$x\leq 3 $$

Determine the boundary curves.

Calculate the mutual intersections of all boundary curves.

I know a method to do this called strokes theorem but there are a few things missing to use that method. Can someone please suggest a way to solve this question or give an answer. Thank you

Comment: @Narasimham I have done that. And what after that ?

Comment: The first one is a solid ellipse with center $(3,0)$, the second one is a half-plane whose boundary crosses the center. so your figure is a solid half-ellipse. The best way to visualize this is plot them in a graphic application (eg. GeoGebra), once you have the plot, everything becomes obvious.

Comment: @ Ozcan After that show it to us. Why do you want to bring in Stokes ( spelling)  thm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region $D$ is drawn in the picture below. The intersection points are self evident.

The function to integrate is missing :)

---

$$...$$

[image]